# Application deployment in pythonanywhere

Tags: python, django, github, window, pythonanywhere

Right now am only trying to work on the console of pythonanywhere I tried to put this following command but it would display "syntax errors:invalid syntax " -: "pa_autoconfigure_django.py --python=3.8.0 https://github.com//my-first-blog.git" Note that I have already installed pythonanywhere using the pip. What do I do? I notice that  PythonAnywhere is based on Linux.

Comment: hi there, pythonanywhere dev here. If you send us an email / feedback from our platform, and tell us which console you are having problems with, then we could potentially examine that console and help you debug. you may also want to provide the full error stack trace here if you want others to help you further

Comment: I am having problem with the pythonanywhere console. I clicked on the console tab of pythonanywhere so as to run the helper to automatically configure my app from GitHub then I typed in the following command " pa_autoconfigure_django.py --python=3.8.0 https://github.com/<my-github-username>/my-first-blog.git " I got an error (syntax error : invalid syntax) please,what do I do?

Comment: again, I would suggest either (1) giving the full error traceback so everyone could help, or (2) sending us at PythonAnywhere an email with your username/with your console link so that we can help you debug

Comment: email: freddyparc@gmail.com,username: freddyparc and console link: python3.8 console 14722248. Having type my github username and the application with the prefix of "pa_autoconfigure_django.py --python=3.8.0" I got an error( Syntax error : invalid syntax)

Comment: Conrad,please check the error I would like to post on the Ask Question in this site because there is no way I could post on this add comment.

Comment: aha. the reason you are seeing that error is because you are trying to run command line code from a python console. start a bash console and you should be able to run the command successfully.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best tutorial for hosting a django app
[Try this](https://deploydjango.blogspot.com/?m=1)